# enable/disable Objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am totally new in programmation and unity, so I have hard time with basically everything!

Here is my issue : I have a 2D static game with a grid of boxes. each box is made of buttons to click.
I want all the boxes but one not visible at the beginning, and then the box have a button to make boxes appears one by one.

here is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   
        private GameObject boite1;


        void Start()
        {
            box1 = GetComponent<Box1> ();
        }


        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                box1.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    
}
```

The "Box1" is underline in red with message : CS0246,  The type or namespace name could not be found.
I am not sure I know how to refer to the game object.

thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you explain how your scene is set up? Is the OpenBox script assigned to each button? Does each box have a button child?

Comment: It is an idle game. I have a central box with 2 buttons, one to gain money by clicking, one to buy things. Clicking on this second button, you can buy the access to other boxes. If you buy the first time, a new box will appear next to the first one. All other boxes don't have access to this fonctionnality.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

more detail [unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)